# URI routing in CodeIgniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, routes, uri

This link works `site.tv/admin/edit/ (controllers/admin/edit.php)`, but this doesn't work `site.tv/admin/reg/edit/ (controllers/admin/reg/edit.php)`   Is it too long path to controller?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your routing should be index.php/CLASS/METHOD/ID

Quote from application/config/routes.php

> Typically there is a one-to-one relationship between a URL string
>   and its corresponding controller class/method. The segments in a
>   URL normally follow this pattern:
>
> example.com/class/method/id/

for example

```
class test extends CI_Controller{

    public function hello() {
        echo 'hello world';
    }

    public function meep() {
        echo 'meeeeeep';
    }

    public function param($value){
            echo 'Your parameter is '. $value;
    }
}
```

Then your url should be `index.php/test/hello`, `index.php/test/meep` and `index.php/test/param/whataeverhere`

**UPDATE**:

If you need "multiple packages" create subdirectories for your "packages" like in

```
controllers
    ->admin
           ->reg
                ->myfile.php
                ->myfile2.php
           ->reg2
                ->myfile.php
                ->myfile2.php
```

and then create your custom routes in `routes.php` under `application/config/` folder

Comment: But if I want to create multiple packages

Comment: @VITr what do you mean by "multiple packages" ?

Comment: For exmaple, we've got `admin` package, which stores admin related controllers. In that package create some new for work with registration, product lists. admin/reg/   admin/products/ - in that packages then create controllers for all kind of operations

Answer (score -1):

I think it's a problem to CHMOD.
check if reg fils it's readeable.

Comment: Checked permission, but it still returns 404 Page Not Found